# Umbraco - Finding Root Node in C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm working on a backend module, so `Node.GetCurrent()` is not an option.  I need to find a way to call something like `Node currentNode = new Node(parentNodeId);` and get the root node of the site.  I've seen samples in XSLT, but nothing for C#.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Even just getting the ID of the root node so I can call `new Node()` would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The rootnode is always available as:

```
var rootNode = new Node(-1);
```

Answer (score 10):

Update for Umbraco 7 (may work in earlier versions too)

```
@{
    var siteroot = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
}
```

For further info, check out the documentation -> http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Querying/DynamicNode/Collections

Answer (score 6):

Update for Umbraco 6+

```
public static IPublishedContent GetRootNode()
{
    var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    var rootNode = umbracoHelper.TypedContentSingleAtXPath("//root"));

    return rootNode;
}
```

This just takes a document type alias and finds the root node as IPublishedContent using the current Umbraco context. UmbracoHelper gives you quite a few options off this also.

Answer (score 5):

Brennan is correct,

```
var rootNode = new DynamicNode(-1);
```

works as well!

Answer (score 5):

Umbraco 7:

```
Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot();
```

Comment: [Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First()](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/47125-How-to-get-the-root-node-in-Umbraco-67#comment-168666) might work better.

Comment: @ThomHubers that requires only one root node. If currentpage is in the second root node, this will not work.

Comment: It's an addition to this answer, which returns a list of root nodes, which was not asked for. The best way to retrieve the root node of a node in a non-first tree depends on the use case. I make use of Document Types in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use this one. I like that it's relative so that if you have multiple root nodes you can target both without a foreach loop.

```
IPublishedContent topNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1);
```