# is there a way to return the current site node id via the api in umbraco?

Tags: c#, api, umbraco

Umbraco newbie of course..

I have some code that returns a certain data type contents for a given node id which is detailed here:

[umbraco API: trying to get the document type data for a given site node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620331/umbraco-api-trying-to-get-the-document-type-data-for-a-given-site-node)

That works fine, however I have to know the starting node i.e. in my case the site node id (multi-site umbraco installation).

I also know you can get the master root node via:

[Umbraco - Finding Root Node in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940537/umbraco-finding-root-node-in-c-sharp)

***My question is this...***

From the backend API, is there anyway to dynamically get the current site node ID (first link)?  this is so I don't have to know it in advance.  I think there is an option to get the site id from a querystring.. Page.Request.QueryString["id"] however I am guessing this is returned if the page is a template page, however this is from a backend class?

Is there anyway? or I am barking up the wrong tree! ??

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of your rootnodes are of the same document type, in razor you could do something like this:

> var folderId = @Model.AncestorOrSelf("MyFolderType").Id;

which will search from the current node 'up' or 'backwards' until it gets to a nodetype of the type specified.

another way is available here:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/20742-Getting-the-home-node-using-c

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply!  being pretty new to Umbraco, it's taking a while to understand a lot of the nitty gritty parts.. and so didn't think of traversing upwards to a specific node type.. which I am guessing would be the case..  unfortunately I am not using Razor pages.. actually I have an ASHX page which calls some backend code to work out the logic stuff (using the Umbraco API calls) and then the ASHX page returns the output as JSON for pure HTML/JS pages hosted in an Umbraco template.

I will check that other link though too - but your comments at least gave me the idea thank you

Answer (score 3):

Say you have an Umbraco installation with two sites with their respective Homepages and Pages, e.g

- Content         (-1)

  - Homepage 1    (1000)

    - Page 1.1   (1001)
  - Homepage 2    (1002)

    - Page 2.1   (1003)

In C# the current node can be obtained with

```
Node currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
```

and its corresponding home node can be found with

```
Node currentHome = new Node(int.Parse(currentNode.Path.Split(',')[1]));
```

Now, `currentNode.Path` returns a string of comma separated integers that starts with -1, 
i.e. the root, the master root as you called it, under which all Homepages 'live'.

E.g. the **path** value of Page 2.1 is **"-1,1002,1003"**. When split at the comma, you'll end up with an array with 3 elements indexed 0,1,2. Now, the second one, with **index 1** will give the **id of the home node**. As you can see, the last id is the id of the current node. As an aside, the indexes also tell the level of the node, so the level of a Homepage is 1.

I used the following script on a template that was used on an intranet/extranet and has protected pages. When a visitor follows a link to a protected page, he/she is denied access and redirected to the homepage, which has a member login.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>    

<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.NodeFactory" %>

<script runat="server" language="CSharp">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevents template to be run without proper authorisation
        Node currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
        Node currentHome = new Node(int.Parse(currentNode.Path.Split(',')[1]));
        Boolean HasAccess = umbraco.library.HasAccess(currentNode.Id, currentNode.Path);
        Boolean IsProtected = umbraco.library.IsProtected(currentNode.Id, currentNode.Path);

        if (IsProtected && !HasAccess)
        {
            // redirect to ancestor-or-self::HomePage
            Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
            Response.Redirect(umbraco.library.NiceUrl(currentHome.Id), true);
        }
    }
</script>      

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
    <!-- redirect to home page -->
</asp:Content>
```